# Basing Reputation Rewarded Off of the Rewarder's Reputation

Tags: feature-request, reputation

Has anybody thought about it?

Why doesn't StackOverflow assign reputation points based on the reputation of the user accepting answers?

Let's make it a sliding scale.

If you as a user have X amount of reputation points, your acceptance or aggreeing with an answer assigns more points to that answer than a user with X/10 points.

Thoughts?

Comment: I think this belongs in trashbin.stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score 5):

This is in the same vein as giving higher rep users more votes per answer/question than other users.

Put simply: **No**

Reputation is a level playing field. Why in the name of all that is good and holy would you put up a barrier to entry for people asking a question? It's such a deterrent. We want to *encourage* participation, not just massage the egos of the higher rep users.

Remember, we were all newbies once, too.

Comment: I fully aggre with what you say that we al started at the bottom, but also as you say we did start at the bottom, and the fact that we as programmers are persistant, and the fact that you are at the pc RIGHT NOW, means that you love what you do, so why not reward you for that, as a hard working programmer, you want me to have the same as the next guy that prefers to surf, rather than to have the love that we have???

Comment: A John Skeet Upvote would be the most coveted thing in the world....

Comment: It would probably set you 'over' the max cap with a single button.

Comment: Is that just your ego talking?

Comment: I'm not John Skeet, so no, its not my ego talking.

Comment: Then thats fine, as long as you do not believe you are others, we can avoid conflicting appointments. As you say, appertnly you status, as you say, would accordingly by pure mass of your existance put all "over" if you would ever to aggree with any other's answer

Comment: @Chacha102: No "h" - it's "Jon Skeet"

Comment: 1. The man's name is Jon Skeet. Thou shalt not have other Jon Skeet's. 2. I got rewarded for my participation. Because rewards were fair. I can vote to close, edit, etc, etc. Also, I get a reasonably large number and shiny icons next to my name. What more could you want?

Comment: Should be "Thou shalt not have other Jon Skeets"--no apostrophe necessary.

Comment: I must say, icons make the man. sorry X-)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Eric.  What formula(s) would you employ to determine the scale?  I don't know how much you see it on SO anymore, but on SF it's very apparent when there is a new person who knows what they are talking about and provides added value to the site.  They climb the rep ladder pretty quickly, and rightfully so.  The requested feature would certainly hinder that, especially when you get into large gaps between a long standing member and a new user, such as seen on SO.

Comment: Thats fine, i understand that you aggree that we all should be seen as equals, and that those who have persued their hobby religeosly should hand themselves over as mere underlings.

I do understand that i belive that if i ask a question and a more senior developer gives me some answer, i would like to show him the requiered respect, as you probably like to see anyway

Comment: Think about it dude.  The fact that someone joins a site later in life in no way implies that they are less of a developer.  These are the people who should be allowed to rise in the ranks by having an even scale.

Comment: Why would the requested feature hinder that? If their answers are valuable, they will get upvoted by higher rep members, and gain *more* rep?

Comment: Yes, and as that, their experiance at that point should get them, by others to lead furtehr if they were as skilled as you say

Comment: Because it would also put more weight on the answers of those that have huge reps.  Then there's the question of downvotes.  Is there a sliding scale for downvotes as well?

Comment: If th eanswer is bad i think so, dont you?

Comment: No, or else I would have upvoted your question.

Comment: I can understand that,but i have learnd from ego hogs, that ek weet jy dink jy weet meer as ons maar ons gaan meer gereeld jou wys presies hoe om dinge te doen

Comment: Nope, not saying that I know more than you at all.  Just that I don't agree with your suggestion.  Have a nice night.